# fwrite/write in c code stalls when writing to local disk

Tags: c, local, fwrite, disk

We have data processing code (written in C) that has very large input data and very large output data (both exceeding the size of the memory).  To do the processing, we need to read in only a portion of the input data, and then after processing, output only a portion of the output data.  Our design allows us to hold a segment of the input data in a portion of the memory, and calculate the first portion of the output data (nearly filling the memory), then writing the output (using write or fwrite) to the local disk of the current node.  Then the code will calculate the next portion of the output data, write it out, etc.  until all the output possible from the input data in memory has been calculated and output.

We work on many independent clusters, and on most, the individual outputs take seconds to finish.  However, on two systems we have encountered, the writes to the local disk (whether to the buffer or to the disk) do not start/finish??, so the code stalls.  They will sit for minutes or even hours and not do anything. This will happen only on some of the nodes, only some of the time, and with different delays on the writes (minutes to hours).  If left, other nodes might start to have the same problem, while nodes that did have the problem will suddenly stop having the problem.

We have found a very strange work-around:  we set up a background loop to copy a relatively large file (1 Gb) to the local disk periodically.  When the external copy starts, the write in the C code starts immediately (we see the I/O on IOSTAT suddenly go).  This only works if the file we copy is large enough, which of course means we are reducing the efficiency of our processing significantly.

The two clusters where we have encountered this problem were setup by completely different groups, and utilize different hardware, networks, etc., and the clusters where we do not encounter this problem have similarities to both these clusters.  We do not see any obvious culprits as to why this very basic write stalls.  On the two clusters where the problem exists, some nodes exhibit the problem more often than others, but sometimes are ok.  Nothing else is running when we are running.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What operating system? And version(s)? This smells like an issue with disk queuing in a situation where memory availability is borderline.

Comment: The current system this is happening on is running Linux 2.6.18-164.EL5 (64 bit).  We have pretty careful memory allocation in the code and should be using 90% of the available 64Gb.  The disk is local to the node, and is unused by any other process.  The write we are doing is about 2.8 Gb.  We have tried fwrite, write, and writing it out in segments.  When it reaches the write, one cpu will be 100% busy, but the IOSTAT will show no activity for 10-15 sec, then a small I/O, then no activity again.  The output file grows but slowly in small bursts.